# Problems with ElementCollection / MappedSuperclass / AssociationOverride

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I have troubles to override an association. Reading javadoc http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/CollectionTable.html you can read "See Also:
ElementCollection, AttributeOverride, AssociationOverride, Column" which gives us assume that you can use it, but I don't know how this doesn't work.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractUser {
 [...]
public String getLastname() { ...}
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
    @Column(name="nickname")
    public Set<String> getNicknames() { ... }
```

implements

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Table(name="user_rfcs")
@AssociationOverride(name = "nicknames",
        joinTable = @JoinTable(name = "user_nicknames", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
)
public class User extends AbstractUser {
[...]
}



@Entity
@Table(name="user_rfcs")
@AssociationOverride(name = "nicknames",
        joinTable = @JoinTable(name = "user_rfc_nicknames", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
)
public class UserRFC extends AbstractUser  {
       [...]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`@AssociationOverride` is mentioned in "See also" section due to following:

> If the embeddable class contains references to other entities, the default values for the columns corresponding to those references may be overridden by means of the AssociationOverride and/or AssociationOverrides annotations.

From other side, `@AssociationOverride`'s javadoc says that it can be only applied to entity relationships, not collections of primitives:

> Used to override a mapping for an entity relationship

So, it looks like you can't do it with `@AssociationOverride`, and you have to override `getNicknames()` method with different annotations in subclasses.

Comment: is possible resolve the problem converting the primitive as a embedded object?

Comment: @fphilip: No, `@AssociationOverride` is not applicable to `@CollectionTable` at all.